# Is there a way to append/extend a list with another list at a specific index in python?

Tags: python, list

In other words, I want to accomplish something like the following:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8]
b = [4, 5, 6]
# some magic here to insert list b into list a at index 3 so that
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: For completeness, a = a[:3] + b + a[3:] would also work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can assign to a [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/2555451) of list `a` like so:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> a[3:3] = b
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>>
```

The `[3:3]` may look weird, but it is necessary to have the items in list `b` be inserted into list `a` correctly.  Otherwise, if we were to assign to an index of `a`, list `b` itself would be inserted:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> a[3] = b
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], 8]
>>>
```

---

I tried to find a docs link which explicitly mentions this behavior, but was unsuccessful (please feel free to add one if you can find it).  So, I'll just say that doing `a[3:3] = b` tells Python to take the items in list `b` and place them in the section of list `a` represented by `[3:3]`.  Moreover, Python will extend list `a` as necessary to accommodate this operation.

In short, this is just yet another awesome feature of Python. :)

Comment: Would it be much to ask "why" this works? I mean, intuitively, if we take an array metaphor, this shouldn't work, because there is not "space" between one element and another to add N more elements. Obviously, python implements lists in a way that makes this possible, but I ask: "is there something in the spec that allows us to _predict_ that this should work?" (otherwise it would be a hack). +1 !

Comment: @heltonbiker - Let me go dig through the docs to see if this behavior is documented.  If not, I'll try to explain it myself.

Comment: `a[3:3]` represents the part of `a` comprised between `3` and `3` (i.e. `[]`, but other indexes would give different sublists). It is a sublist of `a`. `a[3:3] = b` assigns the content of `b` to that sublist, regardless of their respective sizes.

Comment: @heltonbiker - Eh, I couldn't find a docs link.  It looks like this is just a neat little feature (hack?) of Python. :)

Comment: This is mentioned by the docs in the tutorial, see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)). They don't show exactly that `a[3:3] = b` will work however they show `a[2:5] = []` which modifies the length of the list by removing elements in the middle, so I'd expect to be able to insert them too. And they *do* explicitly say that modifying the size is allowed (and they never mention that you can do that only at the end, and in fact examples are assigning in the middle).

Answer (score 2):

Try using the sort method as follows:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,7,8]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> a = sorted(a+b)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```